# How to create a keyboard shortcut for printing texts in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Is it possible to create a shortcut which allows me to copy a saved string everywhere I want?

For example let's say the saved string is "Hello" and every time that I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> it prints `Hello` whatever program which accepts text input I am using.

It doesn't have to necessary be a keyboard shortcut, it could be also a mouse shortcut with the right click.

More precisely I want a shortcut which allows me to copy a saved string on whatever web page I am so that I can use the shortcuts instead of typing the password everytime or memorizing it in the site.

Comment: I suspect my answer is not what you are looking for. If so, let me know and I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you install `xdotool` using `sudo apt install xdotool`, you can use this small script and assign any convenient shortcut to it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

bash -c 'sleep 0.5; xdotool getactivewindow type "HELLO"'
```

From `man xdotool`:

> xdotool lets you programmatically (or manually) simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc. It does this using X11's XTEST extension and other Xlib functions.

and `getactivewindow` makes `xdotool` carry out the requisite action on the  the current active window.

Notes:

- if you have powerful hardware, you can drop the `sleep` bit; if not, you may want to increase the `sleep` value
- I haven't tested the script in `Wayland` where currently only a subset of `xdotool` commands works courtesy of `XWayland`.

Comment: how can i use this in order to print "HELLO" on other programs other than the terminal? for example if i wanted to print "HELLO" on sublimetext how should i edit this script?

Comment: No, there's no need to edit the script. It will work in any window provided the window is active (= in focus); that's what `getactivewindow` does. But you have to install `xdotool` and its dependencies. Of course, for each string you want, you'll need a different script with a unique shortcut key. I'm not really sure what it is you want to do. If you edit your question to elaborate, that would be nice.

Comment: i didn't understand what should i do in order to have the saved string on the active window, when i launch the command bash -c 'sleep 0.5; xdotool getactivewindow type "HELLO"'
it types the string only in the terminal

Comment: You need to save both lines to a script, called `hello.sh` and assign a keyboard shortcut to it. Then, when you press the keyboard shortcut, `HELLO` will be typed in the window which is in focus.